# Load pdf using PDF Kit in view only mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios11, pdfkit

I am using following simple code to load pdf form, but i don't want this to be loaded in editable form. I didn't find anything which restrict this to get loaded in in view only mode.

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PdfFormExample" ofType:@"pdf"]];
PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:fileData];
PDFView *pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
pdfView.document = pdfDocument
[self.view addSubView:pdfView];
```

Thanks

Comment: userInteractionEnabled could be a solution

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan this will disable lot of features like zoom, clicking links etc.. i tried that but i am end up with these issues.

Comment: well said. Point to be noted your honour :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to disable the LongPressGestureRecognizer. Something like this:

```
    private static void DisableDefaultLongPressGestureRecognizer(PdfKit.PdfView oPdfView)
    {
        oPdfView
            .GestureRecognizers
            .Where(x => x is UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
            .ForEach((oLongPressGestureRecognizer, nIndex) =>
            {
                oLongPressGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding a blank annotation over other annotations in the document before presenting it.  I added a **makeReadOnly()** extension to PDF document that does this for all annotations to make the whole document read only.

The advantage of this is that all other PDF viewing features still work fine. Here's the Swift code.  You can do something similar with an Objective-C category:

```
// A blank annotation that does nothing except serve to block user input
class BlockInputAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {

    init(forBounds bounds: CGRect, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.stamp,  withProperties: properties)
        self.fieldName = "blockInput"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext)   {
    }
}


extension PDFDocument {
    func makeReadOnly() {
        for pageNumber in 0..<self.pageCount {
            guard let page = self.page(at: pageNumber) else {
                continue
            }
            for annotation in page.annotations {
                annotation.isReadOnly = true // This _should_ be enough, but PDFKit doesn't recognize the isReadOnly attribute
                // So we add a blank annotation on top of the annotation, and it will capture touch/mouse events
                let blockAnnotation = BlockInputAnnotation(forBounds: annotation.bounds, withProperties: nil)
                blockAnnotation.isReadOnly = true
                page.addAnnotation(blockAnnotation)
            }
        }

    }
}
```